# Azure - Microsoft.IdentityModel not found

Tags: wcf, azure

I'm working with a WCF service in Azure, which uses Windows Live ID authentication with the recent deviceid requirements. When I host my WCF service locally in the compute emulator, it works properly, but when I deploy the cloud service to Azure and call it the same way (from another project that uses the WCF service as a service reference), I get the error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I found this post : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netservices/thread/cd139b5c-ad12-4298-af2f-1b2d0136a977

But there are a few problems: 
1. I don't seem to have access to Microsoft.IdentityModel, only System.IdentityModel. I'm not sure why it's searching for something in 3.5 at all, as I'm building in .NET 4.0. 
2. When I choose to "copy to local" on System.IdentityModel, it doesn't change anything.

Any help? I would appreciate it!

Best Regards,
Andy

Comment: Are you referencing anything else in your service that may be referencing Microsoft.IdentityModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is here: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crm2011beta/thread/951f97df-77b8-4659-8032-6a71161a730c.

The CRM 2011 Beta SDK (versions after Dec. 15th) have some helper code that registers the deviceid on Azure. If you're not working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011, the helper code can still be used to help you see how it's done.

Comment: The link above now says 'You are not authorized to perform this action'. Can you share what the answer said?